# Unset remote_image_url in carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have a model with an uploader mounted on image

I'm bulk importing some data where some of the images may be missing/invalid/etc, so I'm trying to ignore these failures. This is what i've tried so far:

```
begin
  product.save!
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  product.remote_image_url = nil # Doesn't work
  product.send(:_mounter, :image).instance_variable_set(:@remote_url, nil) # Also doesn't work!
  product.save!
end
```

I get the same error every time

```
Validation failed: Image could not download file: 404 Not Found
```

How can I unset the remote image url so it doesn't try and download it? At the moment I'm just having to save before setting remote_image_url and getting it back out of the database if it fails

Answer (score 1):

Disable carrierwave's `validate_download` option as per [the docs](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#uploading-files-from-a-remote-location).

Comment: I tried that, but it seems to only be changeable on initialisation. I need to still validate images when created individually, but turn it off just for bulk importing

Comment: Why not fetch the image yourself first with `HTTP.get`.  If it fails, move on, and if it works stick it in a `Tempfile` and pass that to the model.  You may even be able to pass the HTTP response body to carrierwave, but I'm not sure about that.